# What is value (property get set)?

Tags: c#

I have a question about the keyword 'value' when used in a property like this:

```
public string Name
{
    get 
    {
       return myName; 
    }
    set 
    { 
       myName = value; 
    }
}
```

What is value? How does the compiler know what value holds?

Comment: [value (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx)

Comment: Properties are syntax sugar for the methods MyType.GetName() and MyType.SetName(string value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called `Contextual Keywords`, you can from check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

`value` is a keyword in the context of a property **setter** (not getter) that indicates the value which is being set. So, when you call `Name = "Test"` the `value` will be `"Test"` in the `set` method.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you're entirely right. Updating.

Comment: Property getter/setter are in fact methods. `Name = "Test"` will be transformed into a method call: `Name_set("Test")`, where you can think of `value` as parameter of this method.

Comment: @Sinatr - I am aware of this, however the purpose of properties is to facade/hide this away from you. It does not need to be known/realized in order to use properties. :)